# MySQL too many concurrent connections at once

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I was testing JMeter with 200 concurrent users at once for about 30 seconds and noticed that MySQL connection is failing.

The database is well structured with indexing and queries and cache.

Is this a time we need to look at something like MySQL enterprise?

Or is there a way we can improve this?

This is error that I'm getting:

```
Error: 2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Also error is created when `mysql_connect()` PHP function is triggered

Comment: What error are you getting? This question is very vague and not specific enough. You run the risk of it getting closed without additional information.

Comment: Is this an actual real problem on your site or just testing? 200 concurrent connections to DB are quite a lot, plus the first limit you'll face is probably from the server. Apache is configured to handle 150 connections by default, all other connections will be put on wait.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set MySQL global vcariable called max_connections to increase maximum number of connections per one MySQL server. However, you need to aware that increasing multiple connections means more CPU and memory consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `max_connections` variable in MySQL - 200 connections should not be too much of a problem, unless your queries are very complex.

```
SET GLOBAL max_connections=500;
```

If that doesn't help, use your JMeter results to identify which queries take much longer than others (play with ramp-up period and/or max number of users to get a good batch of samples *without connections actually failing*.

These queries, then, need to be refactored and/or the related data needs to be restructured. You can improve query performance greatly if you try to avoid too many joins and nested select statements, even on well-indexed systems. Use MySQL's [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) feature to find out how much work the database is actually doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini, check out

```
mysql.allow_persistent = xx
mysql.max_persistent = xx
mysql.max_links = xx
mysql.connect_timeout = xx
```

They can also be set in your code using ini_set() if your service provider allows it.

see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php